# Passing variables to Executor Service java

Tags: java, android-studio, executorservice

I'm doing data processing on mobile. Between steps of data processing, I log data (array with a size of 17*1100) into a text file in external storage. Because I don't want the mixing of data from different sets of data, I used an executer service to call the logging function one at a time. Data processing is running faster than the logging process and I called the logging function several times in the process. I realized that most of the time, the variable *data* below is covered by a new set of data. The log file is supposed to be like:

```
String string1
double[][] set1    
String string2
double[][] set2
String string3
double[][] set3
```

However, it becomes like

```
String string1
double[][] set3    
String string2
double[][] set3
String string3
double[][] set3
```

It is also weird that the string variable *note* was correctly passed to the logging function, i.e. string1, string2, string3 are correct.
This is the log function:

```
    public void singleEntry_analysis( double[][] data, boolean reversedColumn, String note) {

    Log.d(TAG, "arrive export analysis");
    final double[][] anaData = data;
    final boolean reversed = reversedColumn;
    final String remarks = note;

    Runnable exportRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                 Log.d(TAG, "anaData null" + (anaData == null? "True" : "False"));
                if (anaData != null) {
                    outputStream_analysis.write(remarks.getBytes() );
                    outputStream_analysis.write(("\n").getBytes());
                    Log.d(TAG, "log analysis" + anaData[0][0]);
                    Log.d(TAG," export start: " + remarks+ " " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
              
                    for (int i = 0; i < sensorData.datalength; i++) {

                            for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++) {
                                if (!reversed) {
                                    outputStream_analysis.write((anaData[i][j] + ", ").getBytes());
                                }else {
                                    outputStream_analysis.write((anaData[j][i] + ", ").getBytes());
                                }
                            }

                        outputStream_analysis.write(("\n").getBytes());
                    }
                    outputStream_analysis.write(("\n").getBytes());
                    Log.d(TAG, "analysis data logged");
                    Log.d(TAG, "from single entry analysis");

                }

                Log.d(TAG," export ends: " + remarks+ " " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    exAnalysisService.submit(exportRunnable);
```

This is how I call the function in other class: I make sure the variable is final before running

```
    double[][] log1 = new double[17][sensorData.datalength];
    log1[0] = time;
    for (int i= 0; i < 8; i++){
        log1[i+1] = sensorFSR [i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<9; i++){
        log1[i+8] = sensorIMU[i];
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "export data, 3rd filter");
    final double [][] log_final = log1;
    MainActivity.exportData.singleEntry_analysis(log_final, true,"3rd filtered");
```

I set the double[][] to final again to make sure no other functions are going to change its value.
Also, if I run the code with debug mode, slowly stopping at the steps before I would like to record, the log file output is correct.

Comment: Please note that you are using a final array of double. This only means that the array definition is final and you cannot assign a new array to this definition, however the elements of the array are not final and there is no guarantee that their values remain unchanged.

Comment: A more reliable solution would be to clone the variables you are going to log into a new array, but this way your code will be consuming considerably more memory and time.

Comment: Yes, I tried on with different variables like log1, log2, log3 for each step to avoid this. The same still occurs, I suspect that the double variable within the singleEntry_analysis has been covered. However, it is so odd that the string has not as I mentioned in the post.